# "No module named site" when embedding python in c++ in Visual studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, python-embedding

there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but I couldnt find any helpful.
I am embedding python in c++ in visual studio. My python is in anaconda, and the directory for anaconda is c:/anaconda2, my code is very simple

```
#include <Python.h>
int main()
{
  Py_initialize();
}
```

I am so surprised even this simple code generates the error

> ImportError: No module named site

And I have set `PYTHONHOME=c:\Anaconda2\python27`, `PYTHONPATH=c"\Anaconda2\libs`, and appended `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` to system variable `path`. I also put `C:\Anaconda2\libs\python27` into `Library Directories` in the property sheets. But I still getting this `ImportError`, can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you actually set PYTHONPATH to what you put in your question because if you did that's probably your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`site.py` is in `C:\Anaconda2\Lib`, after appending `PYTHONPATH` with `C:\Anaconda2\Lib`, problem solved. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938191/can-not-import-numpy-in-boost-python)