# can not import numpy in boost-python

Tags: c++, numpy, boost-python, python-embedding

I am trying out boost-python. However, even a simple hello world doesn't work.

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include <boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp>
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

 void init_numpy()
{
  import_array();
}

 int main()
 {
     Py_Intialize();
     init_numpy();       

 }
```

It gives error

> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

But if I open my IPython, and run `import numpy.core.multiarray`, it runs fine. What part am I getting worng?

Comment: When do you get the error? On compilation time?

Comment: @Kochoba Unlikely, that's an error from the Python runtime.

Comment: Most likely the executable is using a different Python environment than the one used in IPython, so numpy is not available.

Comment: @DanMašek, what do you think the reason? I compared the `sys.path` in the executable, `C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages` is in both paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by by realizing that the Anaconda2 on my windows was not registered during installation (even `sys.path` is the same as that in IPython), I uninstalled it and reinstalled it, during installation I chose to register in the windows, now my code is working fine.